# BrowserTransferStateModule prevent caching

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I use BrowserTransferStateModule on app.module.ts because I build a SSR,

and on one component I have interval that calls httpClient every n-second,

and when running it's only fired once because httpClient/interval hit the same url.

How to prevent caching only for this request?

refs: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some query parameters to the requested URL, so that's its different everytime you make the call. Here is a simple example with current date/time.

```
let date = new Date();
let cb = `${date.toLocaleDateString()}-${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
const params = new HttpParams()
.set('cacheBuster', cb);


return this.httpClient.get('http://yourUrl', {params});
```